# Why am I getting a StackOverflowError in my JUNIT Test?

Tags: java, junit

## Info

For our school assignment we had to make a 'maze' and recursively depth first search through it. While doing that, we have to store the solution to the maze.

I decided to use an adjacency list and loop through that.

## My question.

When I execute the **application**. The code runs *fine* and outputs a total of 37 steps before the maze reaches the end goal.

Once I try to execute my **JUnit4 test**. I get a 'StackOverflowError'.

Why does this happen? And how do I fix this? Any help is much appreciated!

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.HashSet.iterator(HashSet.java:173)
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:74)
    at main.models.Maze.getNeighbours(Maze.java:126)
    at main.models.Maze.dfs(Maze.java:65)
    at main.models.Maze.dfs(Maze.java:70)
    ...etc
```

## Code

### main/Maze.java

```
package main.models;

import com.github.cliftonlabs.json_simple.JsonArray;
import com.github.cliftonlabs.json_simple.JsonException;
import com.github.cliftonlabs.json_simple.JsonObject;
import com.github.cliftonlabs.json_simple.Jsoner;
import main.exceptions.MazeIsEmptyException;
import main.utils.Color;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * This class represents the Maze itself.
 * It contains the nodes and connections to other nodes.
 */
public class Maze {

    /**
     * Stores all the Nodes and connections in a map
     * You may also see it as an adjacency list.
     */
    private Map<Node, Set<DirectedLine>> adjList = new LinkedHashMap<>();;

    /**
     * The starting state.
     * (The state contains where the Pawn's are).
     */
    private State startState;

    // Represents the finish number/id for a node.
    private static int FINISH = -1;

    public List<State> run() {
        this.init();
        return dfs(startState, new HashSet<>());
    }

    /**
     * Recursively searches depth-first. Also includes backtracking.
     * This transverses through the maze. Looking at the color of the Node a pawn is on. And moves the other pawns accordingly.
     * It stores the path it has taken, and if a path proves to be a dead-end it will go back to a previous state
     *
     * @param start Current state in which it will transverse
     * @param visited States it has visited
     * @return An array with the solution or an empty array (no solution)
     */
    private LinkedList<State> dfs(State start, Set<State> visited) {
        LinkedList<State> solution;
        visited.add(start);

        // The solution has been found
        if (isGoalState(start)) {
            solution = new LinkedList<State>();
            solution.add(start);
            return solution;
        }

        // The solution has not been found yet
        else {
            // Get neighbours of the current state
            List<State> neighbours = getNeighbours(start);

            // Try the neighbours and come to a solution
            for(State neighbour : neighbours) {
                if (!visited.contains(neighbour)) {
                    solution = dfs(neighbour, visited);
                    if (goalIsReached(solution)) {
                        solution.addFirst(start);
                        return solution;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // No solution was found
        // Return an empty list.
        return new LinkedList<State>();
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the current state is in a FINISHED position
     *
     * @param state State to check
     * @return true if a pawn is on the finish node. Otherwise false
     */
    private boolean isGoalState(State state) {
        return state.getPawn1().getCurrentNode().getNumber() == FINISH || state.getPawn2().getCurrentNode().getNumber() == FINISH;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the array contains a solution
     *
     * @param list List of states (path it has taken)
     * @return true if a solution was found, otherwise false.
     */
    private boolean goalIsReached(LinkedList<State> list) {
        return !list.isEmpty();
    }

    /**
     * Gets the possible states (neighbors) of a current state
     * E.G. If Pawn1 is on green, it will return neighbors for Pawn2 which are connected by green lines.
     * This gets stored in a list with possible states to explore.
     *
     * @param state Current state of the pawns
     * @return A list of new possibilities to explore
     */
    private LinkedList<State> getNeighbours(State state) {

        // Init a new LinkedList
        LinkedList<State> neighbours = new LinkedList<>();

        // The Pawns from the current state
        Pawn pawn1 = state.getPawn1();
        Pawn pawn2 = state.getPawn2();

        // Gets all the lines (connections to other Nodes) for the pawns and store them in a Set.
        Set<DirectedLine> set1 = adjList.get(pawn1.getCurrentNode());
        Set<DirectedLine> set2 = adjList.get(pawn2.getCurrentNode());

        // Loops through the lines for Pawn1
        set1.forEach(line -> {

            // If the line color equals the color of the node Pawn2 is on
            if (line.getColor().equals(pawn2.getCurrentNode().getColor())) {
                // Create a new possible state
                State new_state = new State(new Pawn(line.getPointsTo()), pawn2);

                // Push it to the neighbors array
                neighbours.add(new_state);
            }

        });

        // Loops through the lines for Pawn2
        set2.forEach(line -> {

            // If the line color equals the color of the node Pawn1 is on
            if (line.getColor().equals(pawn1.getCurrentNode().getColor())) {

                // Create a new possible state
                State new_state = new State(pawn1, new Pawn(line.getPointsTo()));

                // Push it to the neighbors array
                neighbours.add(new_state);
            }

        });

        // Finally, return the new states
        return neighbours;
    }

    /**
     * Creates the Maze and sets a starting state
     */
    public void importMaze(String filename) throws MazeIsEmptyException {
        // Open file maze.json
        try (FileReader fileReader = new FileReader((new File("").getAbsolutePath() + "/src/" + filename))) {

            // Put contents into a JsonArray
            JsonArray nodes_array = (JsonArray) Jsoner.deserialize(fileReader);

            // Loop through the JsonArray
            for (Object json_object : nodes_array) {

                // Cast to JsonObject
                JsonObject node = (JsonObject) json_object;

                // Get the Color of node
                Color color = Color.valueOf((String) node.get("color"));

                // Get number/id of node
                int number = ((BigDecimal) node.get("number")).intValue();

                // Add the node to the adjenency list.
                adjList.put(new Node(number, color), new HashSet<DirectedLine>());
            }

            for (Object json_object : nodes_array) {

                // Cast to JsonObject
                JsonObject node = (JsonObject) json_object;

                // Get the Color of node
                Color color = Color.valueOf((String) node.get("color"));

                // Get number/id of node
                int number = ((BigDecimal) node.get("number")).intValue();

                // Get the Lines from the JsonArray
                JsonArray lines = (JsonArray) node.get("lines");

                // Loop through the lines
                for (Object json_line : lines) {

                    // Cast to a JsonObject
                    JsonObject line = (JsonObject) json_line;

                    // Get color of the line
                    Color color_line = Color.valueOf((String) line.get("color"));

                    // Get the NUMBER of the node it points to.
                    int pointsTo = ((BigDecimal) line.get("pointsTo")).intValue();

                    // We have to find the node it should direct to.
                    for (Node key : adjList.keySet()) {

                        // The node we are looking for
                        if (key.getNumber() == pointsTo) {
                            adjList.get(new Node(number, color)) // To find the node, we make an identical node and use it to search the list.
                                    .add(new DirectedLine(color_line, key)); // When we found the node, we add the new directed line to it. The KEY is the Node we found.
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

            if (adjList.size() == 0) throw new MazeIsEmptyException("The maze is empty.");
        } catch (IOException | JsonException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void init() {
        int nr_node1 = 1;
        int nr_node2 = 2;

        Node node1 = null;
        Node node2 = null;

        // We have to find the node it should direct to.
        for (Node key : adjList.keySet()) {

            // The node we are looking for
            if (key.getNumber() == nr_node1)
                node1 = key;

            else if (key.getNumber() == nr_node2)
                node2 = key;
        }

        assert node1 != null;
        assert node2 != null;

        this.startState = new State(new Pawn(node1), new Pawn(node2));
    }

    /**
     * Prints the Maze.
     *  - All the nodes (+ colors)
     *    - All the connected lines (+ colors)
     */
    public void printMaze() {

        // Loop through all nodes
        for (Map.Entry entry : adjList.entrySet()) {
            Node node = (Node) entry.getKey();
            Set<DirectedLine> set = (Set<DirectedLine>) entry.getValue();
            final String[] lines = {""};

            // Loop through lines set and format the connections
            set.forEach(line -> lines[0] += String.format("[%s, pointsTo: Node%d (%s)] ", line.getColor(), line.getPointsTo().getNumber(), line.getPointsTo().getColor()));

            // Print the node
            System.out.printf("%d (%s) - Lines: %s\n", node.getNumber(), node.getColor().toString(), lines[0]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Adds a Node to the adjacency list.
     *
     * @param number number/id of the Node
     * @param color color of the node
     * @return The created node
     */
    private Node addNode(int number, Color color) {
        Node node = new Node(number, color);
        adjList.put(node, new HashSet<DirectedLine>());

        return node;
    }

    /**
     * Adds a connection line to a node
     *
     * @param node The node to add the line to
     * @param directedLine The line to be added
     */
    private void addEdge(Node node, DirectedLine directedLine) {
        adjList.get(node).add(directedLine);
    }

}
```

### tests/MazeTests.java

```
package tests;

import main.exceptions.MazeIsEmptyException;
import main.models.Maze;
import main.models.State;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class MazeTests {

    private Maze maze;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        maze = new Maze();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        maze = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void totalStepsShouldBe37() throws MazeIsEmptyException {

        maze.importMaze("main/maze.json");

        // Run and store the result.
        List<State> result = maze.run();

        assertEquals(37, result.size());

    }

    // Let op, Als deze loopt dan werkt de eerste test niet...
    @Test(expected = MazeIsEmptyException.class)
    public void emptyMazeShouldThrowException() throws MazeIsEmptyException {

        maze.importMaze("main/empty_maze.json");

        maze.run();

    }

}
```

### main/maze.json

```
[
    {
        "number": -1,
        "color": "BLUE",
        "lines": [ ]
    },
    {
        "number": 1,
        "color": "PINK",
        "lines": [
            {
                "color": "PINK",
                "pointsTo": 4
            },
            {
                "color": "BLACK",
                "pointsTo": 5
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "number": 2,
        "color": "BLACK",
        "lines": [
            {
                "color": "GREEN",
                "pointsTo": 6
            },
            {
                "color": "PINK",
                "pointsTo": 12
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "number": 3,
        "color": "GREEN",
        "lines": [
            {
                "color": "ORANGE",
                "pointsTo": 1
            },
            {
                "color": "ORANGE",
                "pointsTo": 4
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "number": 4,
        "color": "GREEN",
        "lines": [
            {
                "color": "BLACK",
                "pointsTo": 13
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "number": 5,
        "color": "GREEN",
        "lines": [
            {
                "color": "ORANGE",
                "pointsTo": 9
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "number": 6,
        "color": "ORANGE",
        "lines": [
            {
                "color": "GREEN",
                "pointsTo": 9
            },
            {
                "color": "PINK",
                "pointsTo": 10
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "number": 7,
        "color": "ORANGE",
        "lines": [
            {
                "color": "GREEN",
                "pointsTo": 2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "number": 8,
        "color": "PINK",
        "lines": [
            {
                "color": "PINK",
                "pointsTo": 3
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "number": 9,
        "color": "PINK",
        "lines": [
            {
                "color": "GREEN",
                "pointsTo": 4
            },
            {
                "color": "BLACK",
                "pointsTo": 14
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "number": 10,
        "color": "BLACK",
        "lines": [
            {
                "color": "GREEN",
                "pointsTo": 15
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "number": 11,
        "color": "ORANGE",
        "lines": [
            {
                "color": "PINK",
                "pointsTo": 10
            },
            {
                "color": "GREEN",
                "pointsTo": 12
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "number": 12,
        "color": "PINK",
        "lines": [
            {
                "color": "GREEN",
                "pointsTo": 7
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "number": 13,
        "color": "ORANGE",
        "lines": [
            {
                "color": "GREEN",
                "pointsTo": 8
            },
            {
                "color": "GREEN",
                "pointsTo": 18
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "number": 14,
        "color": "GREEN",
        "lines": [
            {
                "color": "GREEN",
                "pointsTo": -1
            },
            {
                "color": "ORANGE",
                "pointsTo": 20
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "number": 15,
        "color": "ORANGE",
        "lines": [
            {
                "color": "PINK",
                "pointsTo": -1
            },
            {
                "color": "GREEN",
                "pointsTo": 22
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "number": 16,
        "color": "GREEN",
        "lines": [
            {
                "color": "GREEN",
                "pointsTo": 15
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "number": 17,
        "color": "GREEN",
        "lines": [
            {
                "color": "BLACK",
                "pointsTo": 11
            },
            {
                "color": "PINK",
                "pointsTo": 12
            },
            {
                "color": "BLACK",
                "pointsTo": 16
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "number": 18,
        "color": "BLACK",
        "lines": [
            {
                "color": "ORANGE",
                "pointsTo": 9
            },
            {
                "color": "ORANGE",
                "pointsTo": 20
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "number": 19,
        "color": "ORANGE",
        "lines": [
            {
                "color": "GREEN",
                "pointsTo": 18
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "number": 20,
        "color": "GREEN",
        "lines": [
            {
                "color": "ORANGE",
                "pointsTo": 21
            },
            {
                "color": "BLACK",
                "pointsTo": 19
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "number": 21,
        "color": "BLACK",
        "lines": [
            {
                "color": "ORANGE",
                "pointsTo": 22
            },
            {
                "color": "BLACK",
                "pointsTo": -1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "number": 22,
        "color": "BLACK",
        "lines": [
            {
                "color": "ORANGE",
                "pointsTo": 17
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

### main/empty_maze.json

```
[ ]
```

## EDIT 1:

### main/models/State.java

```
package main.models;

/**
 * Represents a State
 * Stores the position of the pawns
 */
public class State {

    /**
     * Represents the first Pawn
     */
    private Pawn pawn1;

    /**
     * Represents the second Pawn
     */
    private Pawn pawn2;

    public State(Pawn pawn1, Pawn pawn2) {
        this.pawn1 = pawn1;
        this.pawn2 = pawn2;
    }

    public Pawn getPawn1() {
        return pawn1;
    }

    public Pawn getPawn2() {
        return pawn2;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "State{" +
                "pawn1=" + pawn1 +
                ", pawn2=" + pawn2 +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like you have an infinite recursion. Check your break conditions for the recursion.

Comment: What is `State` and does it have a good `equals` and `hashCode` implementation, so the `visited` set works correctly?

Comment: The state stores the position of the pawns on the maze. I have added it to the main question. My frustrations are: It works fine if you run the app! It's just the tests that don't work!

Comment: From where are you running your app! Is there any difference in the code between that and the test case? Ideally if you are processing the same code lines there shouldn't be an issue

Comment: I am running it from the main package in a class called 'Application'. The code is identical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this by adding hashcode and equals methods to all my classes. This fixed any inconsistencies.

After that I updated JUnit4 to Junit5 and then all my problems were resolved.